# CPP if elseif statement issues

Tags: c++

h value can be between 0<400 or even more, the below coding practise looks tedious...any better thought?

```
if (h<=40) {
  nOfRound = 1;
} else if (40<h<=80) {
  nOfRound = 2;
} else if (80<h<=120) {
  nOfRound = 3;
} else if (120<h<=160) {
  nOfRound = 4;
} else if (160<h<=200) {
  nOfRound = 5;
} else {
  qDebug() <<"too big";
  nOfRound = 6;
}
```

Comment: Well, yes, there's a clear pattern and a truncating division operation.

Comment: `a<b<=c` doesn't mean what you think it does. What you're thinking of has to be written as `a<b && b<=c`.

Comment: There's no point in checking that `N<h` in the else path of `h<=N` (even if the condition was written properly).

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
if (h <= 200) { nOfRound = h / 40 + 1; }
else          { nOfRound = 6; qDebug << "too big"; }
```

(Note that division by a constant is actually pretty efficient, since it is typically implemented by a (fast) multiplication rather than a dynamic division.)

Comment: good syntax, however, one mistake, nOfRound is always 1 less,if h is 79 nOfRound should be 2, the above answer is 1, how about this nOfRound=h/40+1;

Comment: For more division optimization, the factors of 40 are 8 * 5, which means `nOfRound = (h >> 3) / 5;`

Comment: @Thomas Matthews,  h>>3?

Comment: @user3055385: `h >> 3` shifts the value in `h` three times to the right.  Each shift to the right is a divide by a power of 2.  So, shifting right 3 times is the equivalent of dividing by 8, without using division.

Comment: @user3055385: Bit-shift by 3, i.e. divide by 8. But there's little point, since dividing by 5 and dividing by 40 will both produce similarly expensive operations, and in any event, your compiler can figure this out better than you.